# AttributeError: module 'scipy.misc' has no attribute 'imresize'

Tags: python, tensorflow, scipy

Tengo la versión 1.3.0 de Scipy instalada; sin embargo al momento de ejecutar el archivo principal; muestra el siguiente error:

***cnn_glasses.py**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "cnn_glasses.py", line 305, in <module>
model.print_inside_cnn(img.reshape(model.height_pic*model.width_pics),ins_pred)
File "cnn_glasses.py", line 235, in print_inside_cnn
d = scipy.misc.imresize(d, (56, 56))
AttributeError: module 'scipy.misc' has no attribute 'imresize'
```

He investigado y a partir de la versión 1.0.0; de la librería Scipy ya no está soportando el comando "imresize"; sin embargo, ***¿Cuál es la versión de Scipy que sí soporta este comando para instalarla?***

**Gracias por su apoyo.**

Comment: Tendriaa que instalarte una version anterior a la 1.0.0, tal y como lograste averiguar. Igual, antes del downgrade, siempre es mejor buscar una alternativa a dicho comando. Generalmente, las caracteristicas no se eliminan por que si, si no que apareció algo que lo reemplazó. A veces, la documentación indica la alternativa a usar.

Comment: Si haces la downgrade como parece que esperas que proponga, tu programa podria sufrir errores por usar código antiguo y se volverá incompatible con las nuevas versiones de Python mas rapidamente (si es que aun no lo es). Lo que tambien significa que perderas soporte por estancarte en una versión especifica. Y en ese momento, urgirá encontrar una alternativa de todas maneras (ya que tu programa dejaría de funcionar)

Comment: Parece que tienes suerte. Justo la 0.9.0 es la primera en soportar Python 3. Se me ocurre otra desventaja de hacer un downgrade a mitad de escribir código. Algunas funcionalidades que usas, podrian no existir en versiones anteriores. Eso implica reescribir código y buscar alternativas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En realidad `resize` fue deprecada en la versión 1.0.0 y eliminada definitivamente desde la versión 1.3.0, cualquier versión anterior a esta última conserva la función. Puedes consultar la [documentación oficial](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.2.1/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imresize.html#scipy-misc-imresize). Es cierto que eventualmente podrías instalar una versión más antigua:

```
pip install scipy==1.2.1
```

Pero, es mejor seguir la recomendación oficial y usar la funcionalidad del paquete [`Pillow`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/):

```
from PIL import Image

with Image.open("hopper.jpg") as im:

    # Provide the target width and height of the image
    (width, height) = (im.width // 2, im.height // 2)
    im_resized = im.resize((width, height))
```

Comment: Gracias @Patricio Moracho; muy buena aclaración. He utilizado la librería PIL, y funciona genial¡¡¡